# PHP/MYSQL problem with BIGINT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql database and a table to store stuff from twitter API. When i parse data with PHP from twitter i use mysql_query to insert data into the table.

I have a weird problem with the ID of the tweets:

For example the status update with ID 15861323074113537 (a tweet from google) is stored in the database as: 15861323074114000 (the last 4 digits are altered).

The php query is:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table (id,tw_text) VALUES ($id,'$tw_text')");
```

If i edit the record via phpmyadmin the correct value is stored (15861323074113537). The column is BIGINT.

So i guess something weird is going on with the php function mysql_query and the INSERT command.

Any ideas/solutions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make the size of your int column bigger. For example: int(64) . The number inside represents the number of bits available to store the int.

Comment: Are you sure that the `$id` variable holds the correct number before you make the call - ie is it possible you're mis-parsing it? can you show the evaluated command?

Comment: @ford if it were a schema issue, phpMyAdmin shouldn't be able to set the correct value either

Answer (score 3):

ok found the problem, it wasn't code related. Twitter returns 2 IDs and one of those has 000 in the end. [id_str] => 15861323074113537 and [id] => 15861323074114000

Damn twitter API!

Sorry for the trouble :/

Comment: Just a correction: `tweet.id` as returned from the Twitter API does NOT have trailing zeroes. If it seems to, it's because there's a step in your process that is truncating the number. Take a look at the raw json: `id` and `id_str` will be the same number, though one is encoded in json as a number and one as a string.

Answer (score 1):

PHP integers cannot be that large. When a number that doesn't fit into an integer is used, it is converted to a float. What you are probably seeing is that even the float is not precise enough to contain that many digits. Follow webbiedave's advice and keep it as a string to avoid rounding.

Comment: no, PHP can store up to `9223372036854775807` for 64 bits system

Comment: It depends on the implementation, and he never said that he was using a 64 bit computer.

Comment: OP mentioned the store value is `15861323074114000` ... the problem is last 4 digit reset to `0000`

Comment: Exactly. If the implementation is storing the value in a float, it will still be rounded off if there are too many digits.

Comment: huh ? how a float can still represent in `15861323074114000` ?

Comment: ok found the problem, it wasn't code related. Twitter returns 2 IDs and one of those has 000 in the end. [id_str] => 15861323074113537 and [id] => 15861323074114000

Comment: OK, so it wasn't actually the problem, but it could have been. A float is represented by 3 parts: a sign, an exponent, and a value. The value is a binary floating point number with each digit after the decimal and an implicit 1 before the decimal. The maximum value value for a PHP float is about 2^1024 AKA a really big number.